# Check number of touches in hitTest - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, gesture, hittest

In my app I have two views, one on top of the other. One of them should receive pinch gestures and, when that gesture is active, also pan gestures. The other, the one below, has to receive pan gestures only.

I've been trying to override `hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?)` in my top view, to then distinguish when I'm in the first case and when I'm in the other, and let the touch pass accordingly.

As the top view will only handle touches done with two fingers, I've tried to check that in hitTest, but both `event?.allTouches` and `event?.touches(for: UIWindow)` return nil. I've also tried to set gesture recognizers to get this info, but of course they are called after `hitTest`, so I've already lost my opportunity to let the touch pass when I get the info.

My question is, is there any other way of knowing how many fingers is the user using before `hitTest`? If not, is there any other way of passing the gesture from one view to another?